# SQL Join Without Temp Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Long-ish story short, I have two individual queries that I want to combine into one better looking one. I previously accomplished this with CTE's, but I need to use SSIS '05 and it does not support CTE's or temp tables - and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it without them.

Like I said I have two separate 'select' statements. One for first averages, another for subsequent averages. The first has an output similar to this:

```
Description            First_Averages
a) xxx                 4.533333
b) xxx                 8.238095
c) xxx                 .5
I) xxx                 2
j) xxx                 2.25
```

and my second 'select' statement's output looks very similar:

```
Description            Subsequent_Averages
a) xxx                 4.225806
b) xxx                 4.393939
c) xxx                 .1428571
d) xxx                 0
f) xxx                 0
j) xxx                 1.666667
```

Using CTE's, I got it to show every description even if the values were null (replacing nulls with 0) and combine them into one (much better looking) output. The desired output that I was able to get with CTE's looks like this:

```
Description            First_Averages            Subsequent_Averages
a) xxx                 4.533333                  4.225806
b) xxx                 8.238095                  4.393939
c) xxx                 .5                        .1428571
d) xxx                 0                         0
e) xxx                 0                         0
f) xxx                 0                         0
g) xxx                 0                         0
h) xxx                 0                         0
i) xxx                 2                         0
j) xxx                 2.25                      1.666667
```

Is there a way to do this without using CTE's or temp tables of any kind?

My code for those first two 'select' statements is as follows:

```
SELECT
description, avg(total_score)
FROM (a long select statement)
WHERE sequence_num = '1'
group by description
order by description;
```

The second 'select' statement's code is exactly the same except for "sequence_num = '1'" is "sequence_num <> '1'".

If you want to see the FROM code, I can update and include it. It was making this post longer than it already is though so I removed it.

I can't find a way to display all the descriptions including those that have null average values and join the averages to the descriptions like I did with the CTE.

Thanks in advance for the tips. Let me know if you need more information, I've been running in circles for a while now trying to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Try CASE expressions:

```
SELECT
      description, 
      avg(total_score),
      avg( CASE WHEN sequence_num = 1 THEN total_score END ),
      avg( CASE WHEN sequence_num <> 1 THEN total_score END )
FROM (a long select statement)
group by description
order by description;
```

Comment: I like your answer way more than mine.

Comment: This worked! Format-wise at least. It doesn't show every description row though, only the ones that show up in the first average and second average combined. So I'm getting a, b, c, d, f, i, and j - still not e, g, and h. Thoughts?

Comment: If `(a long select statement)` doesn't return rows for e, g, or h, then you won't get those rows in the output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you just want to join the two averages with all the possible descriptions.  One way that this could be accomplished that I see looking at what you provided would be to do the same thing you are doing to get the averages, query the dataset that you are creating and doing a join.

For example you could do something like:

```
SELECT 
    a.description
    , IFNULL(b.First_Averages,0) as First_averages
    , IFNULL(c.Subsequent_Averages,0) as Subsequent_Averages
FROM (
SELECT
description--, avg(total_score)
FROM (a long select statement)
--WHERE sequence_num = '1'
group by description
--order by description;
) a
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
description, avg(total_score)
FROM (a long select statement)
WHERE sequence_num = '1'
group by description
--order by description;
) b
ON a.description = b.description
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
description, avg(total_score)
FROM (a long select statement)
WHERE sequence_num <> '1'
group by description
--order by description;
) c
ON a.description = c.description
order by a.description
```

Now that said, that probably is not the nicest way to do it.  Anytime I have to query a queried dataset I always try to see if I can simplify what I am doing.

EDITED to fix the complete absent mindness of how to do a proper join.  (Added the ON clauses)

Comment: Yours conceptually looks right, but I am getting a 'missing keyword' error upon running it. I'm interested in seeing the output if I can get it running though.

Comment: IFNULL might not be the right syntax, it has been a while.  Try ISNULL instead.

Comment: No that's not the problem, the syntax to fix that though is 'nvl'. Should there be an 'on' at the very bottom?

Comment: haha, yea and there needs to be an ON after the other join as well.  I edited the code block to show it.

Comment: I figured, still getting the 'missing keyword' error though. Not sure where that's coming from.

Comment: for subquery `A` you could use `select distinct` instead of `group by description` it's a little less verbose and gets the point across.  Alternatively you could drop subquery `A` and do a full outer join between `B` and `C` replacing `a.description` with  `nvl(b.description, c.description) description`

Comment: @Sentinel - This solved the 'missing keyword' error so thank you! Still missing the description rows from the first answer unfortunately. Will continue working on it. Always helpful seeing the different perspectives

Answer (score 0):

As per the output you're getting, I think the description is an unique column. So, why not `full outer join` the tables on description column.

```
select description, coalesce(first_averages,0), coalesce(subsequent_averages,0) from (
select a.*, b.subsequent_averages from
firsttable a full outer join secondtable b
on a.description=b.description)
```

It will give you NULL for the ones that aren't available. But the coalesce function will be taking the integer 0 in place of null.

EDITED with coalesce.